# Deployed Heroku app only works after refreshing (Node.js, Express.js, Jquery , Css, Html, TMDB API)

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, heroku, production-environment

everyone,

I have an app that allows you to search for movies and tv shows using The Movie Database API. The app is fully functional on Heroku after refreshing the page. By any chance is there a way to speed up the app and allow it to function without the initial refresh.

**Heroku app** 
https://the-cinematic-app.herokuapp.com/

**Github repository**
https://github.com/kimanikelly/Cinematic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `$.post('/token'...` in logic.js.
The problem here is because ajax is async and that means that JS code 
continue to execute.

That's why 
`apiKey = sessionStorage.getItem('token');` will not have time to get value on first coming to the page because your ajax didn't finish his job.

I think that using async false in $.post and $.ajax is deprecated and because a big part of your app logic is dependent on this apiKey, I would put inside your `$.post...` every `.click` that is using apiKey.

Solution 2

I didn't want to write you a concept of async/await and to confuse you
but you can do something like this

1) add async -> tells that your function is async and you need it so you can await promise with response from ajax

```
$(document).ready(async () => {
```

2) await for ajax to finish

```
var token = await $.post('/token').then();
```

Then you can set in sessionStorage or set it variable and use it.

Comment: Or you can learn to use callback functions and learn async properly. https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-async-programming-in-node-js/